# What is the filter expression to only sniff ICMP packets?

Tags: tcpdump, icmp

What is the filter expression to only sniff ICMP packets given the source IP address is 18.23.54.78 and the destination IP address is 12.67.24.89? The filter order must start with the protocol name first, source IP then destination IP.

I tried to use the following expression:

```
tcpdump icmp src net 18.23.54.78 dest net 12.67.24.89
```

But it did not work. Could I please have some help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The following seems to work for me.  I tried it using loopback/localhost addresses.

```
tcpdump icmp and src 18.23.54.78 and dst 12.67.24.89
```